# R library in home directory not picked up

Tags: r

I have various workstations that share their `/home` drive. They run the same Debian 9 and have R installed. The only difference is that some computers have recently be reinstalled from scratch whereas the others have been updates from Debian 7 to 8 and then to 9.

On the older machines I have the R library in my home directory picked up:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/ueding/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                       
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

On the newer machines I see this:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

As the `/home` drive is mounted via the network, the only difference can be in some system wide configuration. What would I have to set up for the library in `/home` to be picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consult R-project intro here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html

`~/R/%p-library/%v` this pattern template should provide same result on all your workstations. If not, then it is not used. So you should maybe check that.

Comment: Ah, so on the older systems there is a line in `/etc/R/Renviron` which reads `R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1'}` whereas on the newer ones it reads `R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3'}`. It seems that Debian just puts the R version there that was present at installation and does not replace the file with updates. Okay, that answers my question!